# running "make install" for android driver install

Tags: drivers, android

I want to be able to install a driver on a rooted android specifically [this](http://plugable.com/products/usb2-e100/drivers) driver. I compiled it with make on my computer, but I need to run `make install`, the android doesn't have the make command. However, the readme said to run  `insmod asix.ko` which resulted in `insmod: init_module 'asix.ko' failed (Exec format error)`. I am running this on a Samsung K Zoom. Any ideas on how to run make files on android or how to install this driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the device; what is its CPU architecture? I'm guessing it is not the same as your computer. You will need to cross compile the driver for whatever architecture the phone is.

Comment: ARM Cortex- A15